# Error when a shared pointer goes out of scope in a loop (Heap corruption?)

Tags: c++, qt, boost, point-cloud-library, heap-corruption

I couldn't find the problem by stepping through the code line by line.

I managed to extract a minimal example from the codebase and it all boils down to the following lines. What the code does is that it reads a 3D point cloud from an object, wraps it into a shared pointer and sends it away with QT's signal engine. The two lines in the middle are causing the error:

```
for(vector<Package>::iterator resit = results.begin(); resit != results.end(); resit++) {
    // [..] Code ommitted
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> c = queryObject.getCloud();


    // The Ptr typedef resolves to boost::shared_ptr<PointCloud<PointT>>
    // (1) Does not work:   
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_ptr(&c);
    // (2) Works:
    //pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);


    emit this->cluster_added(cloud_ptr);
}
// The error always happens AFTER the FIRST iteration
```

The code works when I comment in (2) (comment out (1) of course..). In both versions `cloud_ptr` is a shared pointer carrying cloud - except for the fact that the first time it's a populated cloud while it's not in the second version.

**Edit:** Since you guys pointed it out - I see how messed up the current version is. That's the result of pointless tryouts.. Initially the `getCloud()` method returned a pointer to the cloud. But that version didn't work either. This is the original version of the code:

```
for(vector<Package>::iterator resit = results.begin(); resit != results.end(); resit++) {
    // [..] Code ommitted

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_ptr(queryObject.getCloud());


    emit this->cluster_added(cloud_ptr);
}
```

**Edit #2: Solution**

Turns out I had a huge misunderstanding about boost pointers. The correct approach here is to create the pointer along with the point cloud and then pass the thing to the object:

```
// Object creation
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
// Do some loading..
[..]

// Use the cloud in the for loop
emit this->cluster_added(queryObject.getCloud());
```

[image: Heaperror2]
[image: Heaperror1]

Comment: `cloud_ptr(&c)` um, `c` doesn't look like its dynamic at all. Sending an automatic's address to an object class designed to `delete` it on destruction is wrong.

Comment: You can't "share" a pointer to an automatic variable, the enclosing scope owns it.

Comment: @concept3d this code would equally croak on a single thread. The OP is stuffing the *address* of an *automatic variable* in to a object designed to `delete` said-address. What the address *points to* is honestly irrelevant. That it is *not* from a `new` is the core issue.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes you are correct, I commented quickly without noticing that c was actually allocated on the stack. Hence my question "is `c` on the stack or the heap" I will remove my comment.

Comment: I see the problem here. The current version is the result of sheer frustration. To my defense I have to say that `getCloud()` initially returned a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>*`. But that didn't work either. I think I'll just edit my answer and add the previous code version.

Comment: @Fred If that object (in the old version) was owned by some other entity - such as the point could - you can't claim shared ownership of it. If you want to share the ownership, the old owner must either give it up or participate in the sharing from the start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that are creating a stack-allocated variable here:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> c = queryObject.getCloud();
```

This variable will be destroyed when it goes out of scope, so wrapping it up into a `std::shared_ptr` doesn't make sense.

How you fix the issue depends on the semantics of your `PointCloud` class with regards to copying, but I'd guess that using this line would fix the issue:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud_ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(c));
```

or, if you don't expect that pointer type to change:

```
auto cloud_ptr = {make_shared<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>(c)};
```

Comment: No need to assume. the OP specifically states that type is `boost::shared_ptr<PointCloud<PointT>>`

Comment: The current version is more or less garbage which I produced out of sheer frustration and now that you pointed it out I see how broken the code is. Initially the `getCloud()` method was passing a pointer to the cloud which didn't work as well (same error). The files are quite big so I want to copy as few instances as possible. Could you extend your answer with a solution that works on pointers (assuming that `getCloud()` would return a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>` or a boost pointer)?

Comment: @Fred if `getCloud()` returns a `shared_ptr` you can just call the `cluster_added` function with that. If you are still having memory errors, your issue is most likely elsewhere; perhaps that pointer is deleted at another location or similar.